# Docker postgres doesn't start at build

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, postgresql-9.6

I want do use a docker container to simulate my production environment, so I installed the db and the server in the same container, and not each in his own.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM debian
RUN apt update
RUN apt install postgresql-9.6 tomcat8 tomcat8-admin -y
RUN service postgresql start
RUN service postgresql status # says postgres is down
RUN su - postgres ;
RUN createdb db_example # fails !!!
RUN psql -c "CREATE USER springuser WITH PASSWORD 'test123';"
RUN exit
RUN service tomcat8 start

COPY target/App-1.0.war /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The problem is that the database is down so I am uable to create the user and the database.
If I start the a debian docker container and do this steps per hand everything works fine.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Both including multiple services in one image and persisting data for db in writable layer are not recommended practice. Could u pls try to explain why you're deploying so?

Comment: I want to simulate the production environment, there it is done this way.

Comment: you have postgresql and tomcat server both in the same image in production environment? Or just postgresql and tomcat are in the same network?

Comment: In the same VM.

Comment: Generally, we keep a thin image as possible as we could. There could be other equivalents to simulate other environment. In your case, postgresql and tomcat in the same VM. Maybe --net flag is enough with value host, means that add '--net=host' when executing 'docker run'. With this flag, both containers will be work in the same network namespace. If you still want to make they work in the same CPU/Memory groups, docker possibly is the last tool you need. Since docker works in the opposite way. It provides isolated environments and is good at this.

Comment: The problem is the war file to deploy has a hard coded localhost in it, so  is it impossible to deploy it with docker ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180715/discussion-between-light-g-and-ace-of-spade).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the problem hat in the war file the localhost for the database war hard coded.
Thanks to [Light.G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8438999/light-g), he suggested me to use --net=host for the container, so now there is one container with the database and one with the tomcat server.

This are the steps I followed.

#### Build the docker image

`docker build -t $USER/App .`

### Start a postgres database

We are using the host namespace it is not possible to run another programm on the post 5432.
Start the postgres container like this:
`docker run -it --rm --net=host -e POSTGRES_USER='springuser' -e POSTGRES_DB='db_example' -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD='test123' postgres`

### Start the tomcat

Start the App container, with this command:
`docker run -it --net=host --rm $USER/App`

Answer (score 1):

All the recommendations in the comments are correct, it's better to keep services in different containers.

Nevertheless and just to let you know, the problem in the Dockerfile is that starting services in RUN statements is useless. For every line in the Dockerfile, docker creates a new image. For example `RUN service postgresql start`, it may start postgresql during docker build, but it doesn't persist in the final image. Only the filesystem persist from one step to another, not the processes.

Every process need to be started in the entrypoint, this is the only command that's called when you exec docker run:

```
FROM debian
RUN apt update
RUN apt install postgresql-9.6 tomcat8 tomcat8-admin -y

COPY target/App-1.0.war /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/

ENTRYPOINT["/bin/bash", "-c", "service postgresql start && service postgresql status && createdb db_example && psql -c \"CREATE USER springuser WITH PASSWORD 'test123';\" && service tomcat8 start && sleep infinity"]
```

(It may have problems with quotes on psql command)